# What can be the cause of the external hard drive deactivating?

Tags: windows-8, laptop, usb, external-hard-drive

I've an external hard drive that I have plugged in onto an external USB hub alongside 1 other (the hard drive in mention is for working while the other is for backups).

Now what I'm experiencing is when I'm working in my programming VM that I run on the working hard drive (I hate to have dozens of programs installed on my computer so I put all i need for programming into that VM) time and again suddenly it can't write to the drive any longer where it is located on and that drive disappears from teh explorer list.

At first I thought a defective HDD, but after tests all seemed ok and it can run a few days then it happens again (and that is not the first HDD where I observe this). So I'm beginning to wonder if there is any possible reason for that that I'm overlooking here?

What do I know

- It can happen time and again, but no observable rythm as to when or why
- The other harddrive does not have that problem
- When I unplug the usb device and cut power to the hard drives and then after 1 minute plug it all in again the hard drive works again as if nothing happened (VM gets smashed though).
- When I plug in the usb hub I get messages on my pc that it could run faster (hard drive is USB 3.0 btw and the usb hub should support that).

Comment: Have you checked for a defective USB cable?

Comment: It can be that the controller on the harddrive crashed. When a harddrive ages it can happen. I've seen it happen with a few of my external harddrives as well. The eventlog will make a note of such occurance which you can check to make sure.

Comment: @LPChip nope only entry was that he couldn't find the device (unable to obtain an interface instance for the driver interface)

Comment: @DavidPostill yepp it is the second HDD that I had this on (with different cables)

Comment: @Thomas you are looking at the eventlog on the host, right? not on the VM?

Comment: @LPChip yepp as that is the only one that could log that type of error isnt it?